# Connect to azure api with cordova from localhost

Tags: javascript, cordova, azure

i need to sent calls to rest api of microsoft azure from cordova app, that is located in localhost:8000, but it doesn`t work, and all the data that i need to send is correct. Someone can help me please.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share the example of what you have tried to do somewhere? (do not share any secret keys) So the community will able to help you. There are a lot of places where it can fail, starting with application token authentication.

Comment: What do you mean about it doesn't work? Please clarify your question. What error message have you got, what Azure service or feature you are using. And do you mean it located in localhost:8000 that your cordova app run in development env in localhost:8000 like ripple?